# Thinkpad Extra Buttons above touchpad enable left middle right

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

today i bought ThinkPad L450, wiped whole windows, installed ubuntu and woah extra touchapd buttons works as scrolling on page left scrolls up, right scrolls down and middle dont know...

Is there any script configuration to get it work as it was designed (for mouse clicks)

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you specify which extra buttons you refer to? Do you mean the buttons for the trackpoint?

Comment: yes, these three above touchapd and below keyboard. device is recognized by ubuntu in ls deviced and xinput or what i checked. also it detects event from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution is suggested here: http://vimtips.org/2015/02/20/ubuntu-1410-and-lenovo-thinkpad-x250/

Comment: much thanks, in some part that fixed my problem with gtk missing characters http://askubuntu.com/questions/609225/missing-characters-after-update-ubuntu-14-04  maybe the lightdm restart helped

Comment: Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad L470 and had problem with the left and right "mouse" button above the touch pad not working. This workaround made them work again, thanks!