# Missing characters after update ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gtk

today i have installed on my new Lenovo L450 ubunut 14.04, everything was fine.. after update i rebooted the PC and characters are missing in GTK apps (netbeans, unity is ok, anything else is wrong) for example instead of "Extract here" i have " x r t  er "

I have tried to rollback from grub to prev. kernel. does not helped.

Thankyou

Comment: regarding to solution of other problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/609211/thinkpad-extra-buttons-above-touchpad-enable-left-middle-right  cstich-s answer helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my X1 carbon and it appears I've solved it. The steps I took were:

1. get gnome tweak tool: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. use the tweak tool to disable font antialiasing
3. reboot
4. use the tweak tool to re-enable antialiasing

It seems like a weird fix and I have no idea why it works, but I've rebooted mymachine now 6 times without any missing characters, whereas previously at least half the time I'd have the problem.

Comment: thankyou i dont know if this works but i have solved it. check my comment to my question.